# Error when encoding row-level formula: Syntax error. Missing ')'

Tags: formula

Does anyone know why I am getting this error? AS far as I can tell I have all the ( ) closed?

```
IF(
    ISNULL(LLC_BI__Covenant_Compliance2__c.LLC_BI__Evaluation_Date__c)
    AND(
        (TODAY()-LLC_BI__Covenant2__c.LLC_BI__Next_Evaluation_Date__c) < 0
    ), 
    TODAY() - LLC_BI__Covenant2__c.LLC_BI__Next_Evaluation_Date__c,
    TODAY() - LLC_BI__Covenant_Compliance2__c.LLC_BI__Evaluation_Date__c
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `AND` is in the wrong place. You need to do `AND(first_condition, second_condition)`

So your formula should be:

```
IF(
    AND(  
        ISNULL(LLC_BI__Covenant_Compliance2__c.LLC_BI__Evaluation_Date__c),
        (TODAY()-LLC_BI__Covenant2__c.LLC_BI__Next_Evaluation_Date__c) < 0
    ), 
    TODAY() - LLC_BI__Covenant2__c.LLC_BI__Next_Evaluation_Date__c,
    TODAY()-LLC_BI__Covenant_Compliance2__c.LLC_BI__Evaluation_Date__c
)
```

Sometimes the error messages you get don't match up if you make certain errors.

I prefer to use `&&` instead of `AND` as I think it's clearer:

```
IF(
    ISNULL(LLC_BI__Covenant_Compliance2__c.LLC_BI__Evaluation_Date__c)
    &&
    (TODAY()-LLC_BI__Covenant2__c.LLC_BI__Next_Evaluation_Date__c) < 0, 
    TODAY() - LLC_BI__Covenant2__c.LLC_BI__Next_Evaluation_Date__c,
    TODAY()-LLC_BI__Covenant_Compliance2__c.LLC_BI__Evaluation_Date__c
)
```

Comment: `(TODAY()-LLC_BI__Covenant2__c.LLC_BI__Next_Evaluation_Date__c) < 0` is unbalanced, and you'd be better off doing a direct comparison rather than subtraction and a comparison against 0.

Answer (score 1):

You've missued `AND()` here

All of the things that you want to "AND" together need to be inside of the parenthesis of the `AND()` (or `OR()`).

i.e. to turn the plain language "if X and Y are true" into a formula, you'd want

```
IF(
    AND(
        X,
        Y
    ),
    <value if true>,
    <value if false>
)
```

In addition to that, when you want to use data on a related record, and it's a custom relationship field, then you need to use `__r` instead of `__c`. This assumes that you're referencing data on a "parent" record (formulas cannot reference data on "child" records)

So, with some assumptions in place, what you want here (in plain language) is

```
if the related LLC_BI__Evaluation_Date__c is null, OR if the LLC_BI__Next_Evaluation_Date__c is less than today
then return TODAY() - LLC_BI__Covenant2__r.LLC_BI__Next_Evaluation_Date__c,
else return TODAY() - LLC_BI__Covenant_Compliance2__r.LLC_BI__Evaluation_Date__c
```

```
IF(
    OR(
        X,
        Y
    ),
    TODAY() - LLC_BI__Covenant2__r.LLC_BI__Next_Evaluation_Date__c,
    TODAY() - LLC_BI__Covenant_Compliance2__r.LLC_BI__Evaluation_Date__c
)
```

Comment: So I'm still stuck on the logic here this was my original code and it worked but I was also trying to add a condition that if TODAY()-LLC_BI__Covenant2__c.LLC_BI__Next_Evaluation_Date__c) > 0 is true then it would return 0. Is there a way I can make there be two true statements:IF(
    AND(  
        ISNULL(LLC_BI__Covenant_Compliance2__c.LLC_BI__Evaluation_Date__c),
        (TODAY()-LLC_BI__Covenant2__c.LLC_BI__Next_Evaluation_Date__c) > 0
    ), 
    TODAY() - LLC_BI__Covenant2__c.LLC_BI__Next_Evaluation_Date__c,
    TODAY()-LLC_BI__Covenant_Compliance2__c.LLC_BI__Evaluation_Date__c
)